# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(format: String, Double)'

Tags: ios, swift

I want to save a distance (which comes from two locations) as a number (Int) to be able to sort the tableViewCells by this number...

I tried to save the distance like this:

```
static var takenLocation: Int?

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let lastLocation = locations.last {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        //get job coordinates
        geocoder.geocodeAddressString(job.location) { placemarks, error in
            //get user coordinates
            let myLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)
            //get distance between coordinates
            let distance = myLocation.distance(from: jobLocation) / 1000
            print(String(format: "The distance to the Job is %.01fkm", distance))
            JobTableViewCell.takenLocation = Int(format: "%.01km", distance) -> ERROR
        }
    }
}
```

But through this I'm getting **Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(format: String, Double)'** as an error...
How can I solve this? Or is there another way to save the distance as a number?

EDIT:

```
struct sortJobs {
    let sDistance = JobTableViewCell.takenLocation
}
var sJobs = [sortJobs]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        self.sJobs.sort(by: { ($0.sDistance) < ($1.sDistance) }) -> ERROR
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

I'm now getting 
**Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands**
and
**Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Int'**
as an error

Comment: `Int(format: "%.01km", distance)`? `String(format:)` maybe, not `Int(format:)`? Also, it seems to be missing the placeholder. the `f` (cf. previous one used)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here ? How `"%.01km"` can be represented using an Int ? You want to use `JobTableViewCell.takenLocation = Int(distance)`

Comment: Gonna agree with @MidhunMP, how do you expect the "km" to be represented as an Int? Surely, you are looking for something as a `String`

Comment: But if I declare it as a String there won't happen any sort in the tableView

Answer (score 0):

There is no such initialiser for Int. From your code, you declared `takenLocation` as Int.

So probably you want to use:

```
JobTableViewCell.takenLocation = Int(distance)
```

Or else you declare takenLocation as a String and change your code to:

```
static var takenLocation: String?
JobTableViewCell.takenLocation = String(format: "%.01fkm", distance)
```

Comment: if I declare it as a string, the tableViewCells won't get sorted, so I want to try it with an Int

Comment: @GifHunter111: Did you check the first option then ?

Comment: Yes, but by this it's giving me **Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands** as an error, I'll update my question to this

Comment: @GifHunter111 Use `self.sJobs.sort(by: { $0.sDistance! < $1.sDistance! })`

Comment: Tried it as well, but the cells won't get sorted :( cells with 17.1km are above 0.0km

Comment: @GifHunter111: I tried your code using some test data in playground and it's working fine. Could you please share a sample project which have the issue (if possible)

Comment: Yeah sure, where do you want me to upload the project?

Comment: @GifHunter111 Post it on github or dropbox or any other file sharing sites

Comment: perfect, thank you for doing it - here is the link to the project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/naf523drl425z7t/AADSUtqwJLE5WPOn5O-tgG39a?dl=0

Comment: @GifHunter111: There are some mistakes in your code. 1) sJobs array is empty always. 2) You have only one variable `takenLocation`, so it will hold only the last calculating distance

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a typo (actually two).

`Int` doesn't have a `format` initializer and from the format specifier you apparently want a **string** representation with one decimal place for a `Double` which is `"%.1f"`

```
static var takenLocation: String?

JobTableViewCell.takenLocation = String(format: "%.1fkm", distance)
```

Integers don't have decimal places (and no letters  ). If you want to save the integer portion of the `Double` you could write

```
static var takenLocation: Int? // Consider to declare the variable as non-optional takenLocation = 0

JobTableViewCell.takenLocation = Int(round(distance))
```

Comment: After reading the upper text: `static var takenLocation: Int?` at top of the author's code that might need to change.

Comment: Yes, it is working like you say but I don't want to save it as a string as the tableViewCell's won't get sorted by your code

Comment: It's possible to sort numeric strings. I updated the answer with an alternative.

Comment: thanks for this, but somehow the tableview still shows the cell with a post 60km far away over one which is 1.1 km away:(

Comment: To sort numeric strings `compare` with the `.numeric` option or use the `localizedStandardCompare` selector.

Comment: could you maybe give me an example according to my code for this? the posts online honestly didn't helped much :/

Comment: If `takenLocation` is a string use `self.sJobs.sort(by: { $0.sDistance!.compare($1.sDistance!, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending })`. If `takenLocation` has always a value declare it as empty non-optional string and remove the exclamation marks in the `sort` closure.

Comment: Then use the `Int` (or better a `Double`) version and add `km` when the value is displayed.

Comment: Neither the String nor the Int/Double Version works :( could you maybe check my project (no worries, it's not the complete project, just the needed files)? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/naf523drl425z7t/AADSUtqwJLE5WPOn5O-tgG39a?dl=0

Comment: In the project there are a few bad practices. The purpose of a table **view** cell is to display data but not to retrieve data. A cell can be deallocated immediately. Get the location in the data source **model**. And the *static* variable in the cell can be accessed from all instances simultaneously. This will likely cause unexpected behavior. And what is the location manager in the controller doing?